# Ansible find module does not exclude folder in the search

Tags: search, directory, ansible, find

Here is my playbook where i try to find `test-juli.jar` under `/app` directory however, i wish to exclude `/app/Patchbackup` folder from the search.

Below is my playbook for the same:

```
  tasks:

    - name: Find test home directories under /app
      find:
        paths: /app
        file_type: any
        recurse: yes
        depth: 4
        patterns: 'test-juli.jar'
        excludes: 'log,tmp,.installation,Patchbackup'
      tags: always
      register: tomjarfound

    - debug:
        msg: "ALL LISTED REFINED JARS: {{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ tomjarfound.files }}"
```

When i run the above, i was expecting the `find` not to find under `/app/Patchbackup` but the output shows that it does despite being excluded.

Here is the output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.0.11] => (item=/app/apache-test-9.0.10/bin/test-juli.jar) => {
    "msg": "ALL LISTED REFINED JARS: /app/apache-test-9.0.10/bin/test-juli.jar"
}
ok: [10.0.0.11] => (item=/app/Patchbackup/app/apache-test-9.0.10/bin/test-juli.jar) => {
    "msg": "ALL LISTED REFINED JARS: /app/Patchbackup/app/apache-test-9.0.10/bin/test-juli.jar"
}
```

Can you please suggest how can I exclude the folder `/app/Patchbackup` from ansible's find ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you realized, the `find` module doesn't provide you with an option to start with the root dir of `/app` but exclude one of its directories. You have a few options:

1. if the dirs under `/app` are not many, you can use the clause `paths` to provide a list of them (excluding the undesired `Patchbackup`)
2. retrieve all results under /app and then filter out the ones from `/app/Patchbackup` that you don't want. Here is an example of how to filter them out:

Code:

```
  - set_fact:
      my_results_final: "{{ my_results_final | default([]) + [item] }}"
    when: item is not regex('^/app/Patchbackup(.+)')
    with_items:
    - "{{ tomjarfound.files }}"


  - debug:
      var: my_results_final
```

Comment: Considering I'm dealing with several flavors of operating system I would prefer using ansible `find` than OS `find` as the parameters change of different OS @ilias-sp @larsks

Comment: glad it helped. as the `with_items` loop can be time consuming if you have many iterations, i would say that the "OS find" solution if you have for example hundreds of results to feed in the `set_fact` module. if you wont have a lot, then the above approach is better i think too.

Comment: Is there a provision of specifying a depth in the OS find that works on all flavors of Solaris, Linux and Aix ?

Comment: its been a long time since i worked on Solaris and AIX, pretty hard to check now. but u could run a regular find and then feed the results to a `grep` with regex filter and get your desired results. but again, if you dont expect to have many results, i would go with the "Ansible" solution (the one i provided). i see you are searching for a specific filename "test-juli.jar" so i guess you probably wont have that many results!

Comment: While this works fine, unfortunately filtering using `when` will list every single skipped item in the output which generates a lot of noise.

Answer (score 6):

The `find` module is arguably broken.  The `excludes` parameter applies only to items in the final result set, and **not** to intermediate directories.

That is, if you have a directory structure like this:

```
toplevel/
  foo/
    testfile1.txt
  bar/
    testfile2.txt
```

And from the parent of the `toplevel` directory you run a task like this:

```
- find:
    paths: toplevel
    recurse: true
    excludes: foo
  register: results
```

Your result set will look like:

- `toplevel/bar/testfile2.txt`
- `toplevel/foo/testfile1.txt`

Compare that to setting `file_type: any`, like this:

```
- find:
    paths: toplevel
    file_type: any
    recurse: true
    excludes: foo
  register: results
```

In this case, the result set will look like:

```
- `toplevel/bar`
- `toplevel/bar/testfile2.txt`
- `toplevel/foo/testfile1.txt`
```

Note that `toplevel/bar` is included in the results, but `toplevel/foo` is excluded. That's because:

- We set `file_type: any`, which means we want to find directories as well as files.
- This makes `toplevel/foo` part of the result set.
- We are excluding from the results anything with the basename `foo`

You will get more flexible behavior if you simply use the `find` command:

```
- name: exclude an intermediate directory with find command
  command: >-
    find toplevel -name foo -prune -o -type f -print
  register: result
```

Which will return the following items:

- `toplevel/bar/testfile2.txt`

I've put a runnable version of the above [on github](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-63578783).

Answer (score 3):

Ansible's [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) module's `excludes` parameter operates on *basenames* of files. Per the documentation:

> **excludes**: One or more (shell or regex) patterns, which type is controlled by use_regex option. Items whose basenames match an excludes pattern are culled from patterns matches. Multiple patterns can be specified using a list.

In your case, it is correctly ignoring `/app/Patchbackup/` because its basename is `Patchbackup`, but also correctly including `/app/Patchbackup/app/apache-test-9.0.10/bin/test-juli.jar` because its basename is `test-juli.jar`.

Comment: Your explanation is much clearer than the other answers, but I'm hesitant to upvote it because it doesn't provide any solutions to the problem! ("Can you please suggest how can I exclude the folder /app/Patchbackup from ansible's find ?")

Comment: You are completely correct. I just wanted to point out that the behavior as described in the original question is valid. I should have used a comment instead.

Comment: I dunno, this is a lot of information for just a comment. This *was* the best answer that described the problem so I'll upvote it as well as one of the other answers that helped me solve it. I suppose there's no sense in duplicating information from the other answers at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this omission is to go with `json_query` filter:

```
- find:
    paths: /app
    recurse: true
    patterns: 'test-juli.jar'
  register: results

- set_fact:
    final_result: "{{ results | to_json | from_json | json_query(_query) }}"
  vars:
    _query: "files[?!contains(path, 'Patchbackup')]"
```

you will need to have `jmespath` python library installed. (if I remember it correctly that `| to_json | from_json |` part is needed to deal with another types issue.