# Ansible find module collecting files in hidden directories

Tags: ansible

A couple of tasks in my playbook keep finding and modifying files in hidden directories--I do not want the hidden files to be altered.

ansible-core 2.13.7

```
 - name: Find all script files
   find:
     recurse: yes
     paths: /var/bbb
     patterns:
       - "*.sh"
       - "*.py"
       - "*.env"
   register: script_files

 - name: Make all scripts executable
   file:
     dest: "{{ item.path }}"
     mode: "a+rx"
   with_items: "{{ script_files.files }}"
```

Sample of output from second task:

`ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/var/bbb/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/docker/tests/unit/plugins/module_utils/test_util.py', 'mode': '0755', ...`

I've gone through the docs and they say hidden files are left alone by default in the current and former versions.  I suspect it may be the patterns, but again the docs say the pattern is compared to the file base name and excludes the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your observation

> *Ansible `find` module collecting files in hidden directories*

that's right and the expected behavior.

> *... they say hidden files are left alone by default in the current and former versions.*

I interpret the documentation about [Parameter: `hidden`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-hidden) that it applies to files only and not to directories.

A minimal test setup

```bash
mdkir .hidden
touch .hidden/script.sh
touch .hidden/.script.sh
```

with an example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Find all script files
    find:
      hidden: false
      recurse: true
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/"
      patterns:
       - "*script.sh"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.files }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
...
    path: /home/user/.hidden/script.sh
...
```

or if `hidden: true`

```yaml
...
    path: /home/user/.hidden/script.sh
...
    path: /home/user/.hidden/.script.sh
...
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Using Ansible `find` module to get hidden folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68667905/6771046)

---

To summarize, your question seems to be about

**How to exclude hidden directories from Ansible `find` module `recursive` search?**

Since with the parameter `hidden: false` and `file_type: any` still the `/.hidden/script.sh` is found, the  [`excludes` parameter operates on `basenames` of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63581147/6771046), I recommend to adjust the search path.

Answer (score 1):

Given the useful explanation in the previous answer and the complexity of the search path solution in my use case, I looked beyond the parameters of find and developed a separate task that removes results that contain hidden directories:

```
  - name: filter hidden directories
    set_fact: 
      filtered_list: "{{result.files | map(attribute='path') | reject('search', '/\\.')}}"
```

Be aware that this will remove all paths which contain a hidden directory: it should not be used when the find task is performed on paths that contain a hidden directory.